# Setting Label and StaticText Color property problem - Delphi 2009

Tags: delphi, colors, properties, delphi-2009, panel

When I set the **Label**'s color e.g. on value **clRed**, the red on it only blink for a while. The color property still has clRed value, but in fact it has default **clBtnFace** color.

[Screenshot](http://imgway.eu/data/10672.jpg) discribes the problem better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set Transparent to False. :-)

Edit: assuming it's a TLabel, as shown in the screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean a `TLabel` or a `TPanel`? Your screenshot shows a label, but it should work for both components.

Make sure that the `ParentColor` property is set to `false`.

Comment: Yes, sure, I thought Label, not Panel. :-)