# How do I change the color of a TLabel when my cursor hovers hover it in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

So I tried using the `OnMouseEnter` event for the label and used the code:

```
Label1.Color := clPurple;
```

But that didn't work

Comment: do you want to change the background color or font color

Comment: Please define "didn't work" as in: what did you expect and what has happened instead. Also use formattings in your post and search for existing questions/answers, such as https://stackoverflow.com/q/981510/4299358

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the Transparent property to `FALSE`.

Also, don't forget you need to set the `OnMouseExit` event too.

So the simplest way is to set the color property in the designer, then set the transparent property to `FALSE` in the `OnMouseEnter` event and `TRUE` in the `OnMouseExit` event.

Answer (score 1):

The label can't be transparent to do this  in the event and  labels are transparent by default, so do this:

```
Label1.Color := clPurple;
Label1.Transparent := False
```

Answer (score 0):

```pascal
Label1.Font.Color := clPurple;
```

`Label1.Color` is the background color which is transparent.